# Getting multiple min and max dates from a pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to get the minimum and maximum dates of the two periods where column y is greater than 0.

Dataframe:

```
Date          Y
25/02/2019    0
24/02/2019    1
23/02/2019    1
22/02/2019    0
21/02/2019    1
20/02/2019    1
19/02/2019    1
18/02/2019    0
17/02/2019    0
16/02/2019    0
```

Perhaps return the results in a list. Using the table above I expect to get the following:

```
[[23/02/2019, 24/02/2019],[21/02/2019, 19/02/2019]]
```

How the results are returned is not important. It's getting them. I understand how to get min and max dates if there was only one period where Y > 0 :

```
min(ua_dates['Date'])
max(ua_dates['Date'])
```

Trouble is this gives me 19/02/2019 and 24/02/2019 using the table above. Perhaps there is some sort of library out there?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "dates of the two periods where column y is greater than 0" how are the two periods defined? Do you mean that you would like the min and max of the dates where y is greater than 0 and the min and max where y is 0?

Comment: I define a period as any date(s) connected together where Y is greater than 0. A period could also be a single day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you need select all Y==1 out , then if they are not continue , you want them into different group, here we using `cumsum`

```
ua_dates.loc[df.Y==1,'Date'].groupby(ua_dates.Y.eq(0).cumsum()).agg(['min','max']).values.tolist()
Out[713]: [['23/02/2019', '24/02/2019'], ['19/02/2019', '21/02/2019']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to mask your data:

```
 mask = ua_dates['Y'] > 0
 min(ua_dates[mask]['Date'])
 max(ua_dates[mask]['Date'])
```

Comment: Ps. I included this in the format that you included, but your code will go faster in pandas is you use `df['thing_i_want'].max()` rather than `max(df['thing_i_want'])`.

Comment: check your output ?

Comment: Ah. I think I was misunderstanding how the periods work in this problem. Your answer is more inline with what the asker was asking.